# Views: alter data of a View of another module

Tags: views

I wanted  to add a relationship to data in a View of an existing module, so I've hacked the code (the function `modulename_views_data`) and it works.

Now I want to create a new  module to do this extension, leaving clean the original one. I guess I should use the `function views_data_alter(&$data)` but I don't understand how to bind it to the other module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would [create a module](https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7).  It only needs a simple modulename.info file and modulename.module file.

If you called your module 'mymodule', then in mymodule.module add the function:

```
mymodule_views_data_alter(&$data) { 
  \\custom code
}
```

Clear the caches and you should be good to go.

The hook system allows modules to interact with other modules code. By naming your function `MODULENAME_views_data_alter` you are telling Drupal that you want to take advantage of the hook `HOOK_views_data_alter`.

Comment: It works! I had put this hook in a `views.inc` file to follow the original module pattern.